# Magento 2: Create customer attributes programatically, without install script

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, eav-attributes

How to create customer attributes magento 2 so it works in running script without install script:-

```
    /**
     * @var   \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory
     */
    protected $eavEavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavEavSetupFactory,
        ...     
    )
    {
        ...
        $this->eavEavSetupFactory = $eavEavSetupFactory;
        ...
    }

    public function createOrUpdateCustomerUDA($value, $input, $type)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->eavEavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $value, [
            'type' => $type,
            'label' => $value,
            'input' => $input,
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);
        //add attribute to attribute set
        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, $value)
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

    $attribute->save();
    }
```

I am using this function in my custom module to create customer attributes, but it give me below error, can please guide me how to pass the `$setup` in this function so it's working fine:-

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$setup' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ')' in Customer.php on line 540
```

Comment: I think there is no need to pass ['setup' => $setup] to the factory. Just remove it and everything should be fine.

Comment: After remove ['setup' => $setup] get below error:- `Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup::__construct()`

Comment: `Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface` Can you try to load this in construct and pass its reference as argument for setup argument

Comment: @Pankaj after set the construct dependency get error:- Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Setup\Module\DataSetup::__construct()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long time and debugging and spent time on reading blogging site/forum I found the solution to create attribute in magento to programmatically and able to save value in this custom created attributes.

Here is mu complete code that works in my custom module:-

```
<?php
namespace Company\Mymodule\Helper;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;

class Customer extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory
     */
    protected $eavEavSetupFactory;
    protected $eavConfig;
    protected $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavEavSetupFactory,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,       
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
        ...
    )
    {
        ...
        $this->eavEavSetupFactory = $eavEavSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        ...
    }   

    protected function createOrUpdateCustomerUDA($value, $input, $type)
    {
        /** @var CustomerSetup $customerSetup */
        $customerSetup = $this->eavEavSetupFactory->create();

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEntityTypeId('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerSetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($customerEntity);

        /** @var $attributeSet AttributeSet */
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);
        $attributeCode = $this->getAttributeCode($value);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode, [
            'type' => $type,
            'label' => $value,
            'input' => $input,
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'user_defined' => true,
            'sort_order' => 90,
            'position' => 999,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, $attributeCode)
            ->addData([
                'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
                'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
                'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
            ]);

        $attribute->save();

        unset($customerSetup);      
    }

    protected function getAttributeCode($str)
    {
        return "pre_" . strtolower(str_replace(" ", "", $str));    
    } 
}
```

Please use above code and let me know if any issue.
Happy coding :)

Comment: hi @Purushotam, can you provide the code to create product attribute as well please?

Answer (score 3):

Try following code:

> 1. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    '[VendorName]_[ModuleName]',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/etc/module.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="[VendorName]_[ModuleName]" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Customer"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. app/code/[VendorName]/[ModuleName]/Setup/InstallData.php

```
namespace [VendorName]\[ModuleName]\Setup;

use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Set as AttributeSet;
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\SetFactory as AttributeSetFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $customerSetupFactory;

    private $attributeSetFactory;

    public function __construct(
        CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory,
        AttributeSetFactory $attributeSetFactory
    ) {
        $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerEntity = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getEntityType('customer');
        $attributeSetId = $customerEntity->getDefaultAttributeSetId();

        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $attributeGroupId = $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId($attributeSetId);

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_username', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Custom Field',
            'input' => 'text',
            'user_defined' => false,
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'sort_order' => 1000,
            'position' => 1000,
            'system' => 0,
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(Customer::ENTITY, 'custom_username')
        ->addData([
            'attribute_set_id' => $attributeSetId,
            'attribute_group_id' => $attributeGroupId,
            'used_in_forms' => ['adminhtml_customer'],
        ]);

        $attribute->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: I already find this but this is using the install script. But I want to use without install script