# How to Add Customer Attribute in 2.2.2

Tags: attributes, magento2.2.2

How to Add Customer Attribute in magento 2.2.2 and display it in the front end ?

beacuse i saw mamy post but not working in 2.2.2 thank you!!

Comment: Try using module generators like mage2gen.com and http://www.silksoftware.com/magento-module-creator/magento2x.php

Comment: Refer [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/207078) link.

Comment: is work thank you but not showing on Frontend @KalyanChakravarthiV

Comment: how to showing on Frontend ,thank you! @PratikOza

Comment: how to showing on Frontend ,thank you! @KeyurShah

Comment: Where you want to display that attribute ? Did you select show in frontend as yes while generating the module ?

Comment: yes, selected show in frontend as yes. i want to add Customer Attribute and show it on Account Dashboard , thank you!^^ i can see it on adminhtml but can't see it on  frontend @KalyanChakravarthiV